# TypeScript Compiletime errors

Tags: typescript

```
function padLeft(value: string, padding: any) {
  if (typeof padding == "number") {
    return Array(padding + 1).join(" ") + value;
  }
  if (typeof padding == "string") {
    return padding + value;
  }
  throw new Error(`Expected string or number, got '${padding}'.`);
}

padLeft("Hello world", 4);
```

when i run this program i am getting following errors

:\TypeScriptFiles\Typescript_Intersection>tsc Progrm2.ts
F:\TypeScriptFiles\Typescript_Intersection\Progrm2.ts(8,21): error TS1001: Unexpected character "`".
F:\TypeScriptFiles\Typescript_Intersection\Progrm2.ts(8,21): error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'expression' expected.
F:\TypeScriptFiles\Typescript_Intersection\Progrm2.ts(8,31): error TS1005: ',' expected.
F:\TypeScriptFiles\Typescript_Intersection\Progrm2.ts(8,38): error TS1005: ',' expected.
F:\TypeScriptFiles\Typescript_Intersection\Progrm2.ts(8,41): error TS1005: ',' expected.
F:\TypeScriptFiles\Typescript_Intersection\Progrm2.ts(8,53): error TS1005: ',' expected.
F:\TypeScriptFiles\Typescript_Intersection\Progrm2.ts(8,66): error TS1001: Unexpected character "`".
F:\TypeScriptFiles\Typescript_Intersection\Progrm2.ts(8,66): error TS1003: Identifier expected.

note:i am using VSCode to develop this

Comment: Very strange. Do you maybe have a reaaally old TypeScript version? Template string were introduced in TypeScript 1.4. What is the output of "tsc --version"?

Comment: Is this the whole content of the Progrm2.ts file? (Seems that the compiler balks at the ` in the template string.)

Comment: Version 1.0.3.0 this is typescript version

Comment: yes that is hole content of program2.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied your code and run it with a standard tsc.exe filename.ts and it ran well. It doesn't matter what kind of IDE or Text Editor you use it should perform equally. In a case of VS Code it uses typescript cli.

Here's JS code that was generated:

```
function padLeft(value, padding) {
    if (typeof padding == "number") {
        return Array(padding + 1).join(" ") + value;
    }
    if (typeof padding == "string") {
        return padding + value;
    }
    throw new Error("Expected string or number, got '" + padding + "'.");
}
padLeft("Hello world", 4);
```

My advice to use different environment and check your typescript version. Latest version is 2.1 or something for a moment when I write the comment.